# Organizar botones dentro de List Group Item

Tags: html, lista

Quiero hacer una especie de "To Do List" con botones de borrar y editar pero cada vez que añado un nuevo elemento, estos botones quedan mal organizados, quedan de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo lograr que los botones queden bien centrados dentro de cadfa elemento de la lista?

**Codigo de Insercion**

```
$(".agregarCate").click(function () {

    if ($("#custom_textbox").val() != "") {
        var deleteButton = "<button class='delete btn btn-warning'>Borrar</button>";
        var editButton = "<button class='edit btn btn-success'>Editar</button>";
        var twoButtons = "<div class='btn-group pull-right'>" + deleteButton + editButton + "</div>";
        $(".list_of_items").append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + "<div class='text_holder'>" + $("#custom_textbox").val() + twoButtons + "</div></li>");
        $("#custom_textbox").val('');
    }
});
```

Gracias.

**EDITADO**

Añadiendo `row`al list group, queda asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si necesita una fila dos columnas dentro del `list-group-item`  puede utilizar `flex-box` , al padre se le añade la clase d-flex  y al que desea alinear a la derecha `ml-auto` *(Bootstrap4)*

```js
$(".agregarCate").click(function () {

var deleteButton = "<button class='delete btn btn-warning'>Borrar</button>";
var editButton = "<button class='edit btn btn-success'>Editar</button>";
var twoButtons = "<div class='btn-group ml-auto'>" + deleteButton + editButton + "</div>";
$(".list_of_items").append("<li class='list-group-item'> <div class='text_holder d-flex '>" + $("#custom_textbox").val() + twoButtons + "</div></li>");
$("#custom_textbox").val('');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<button class="agregarCate btn btn-info">Agregar</button>
<div class="list_of_items">
 
</div>
```

Para `Bootstrap3` solo haría falta añadir la clase row al contenedor en este caso a `list-group-item`  ,  es decir `<li class='list-group-item row'>`

```js
$(".agregarCate").click(function () {

var deleteButton = "<button class='delete btn btn-warning'>Borrar</button>";
var editButton = "<button class='edit btn btn-success'>Editar</button>";
var twoButtons = "<div class='btn-group pull-right'> " + deleteButton + editButton + "</div>";
$(".list_of_items").append("<li class='list-group-item row'> <div class='text_holder'>" + $("#custom_textbox").val() + twoButtons + "</div></li>");
$("#custom_textbox").val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button class="agregarCate btn btn-info">Agregar</button>
<div class="list_of_items">
 
</div>
```

Comment: El problema con añadirle row es que la lista se corre y queda desalineada con los elementos del boton y text, lo resolvi añadiendo `<br/>`despues de los botones, igual excelente respuesta como siempre.

Comment: bootstrap 4, añado una imagen el post de como queda añadiendole row

Comment: @Baker1562 tener en cuenta que no añado row para bootstrap4 , solo para bootstrap3. Saludos.